# How can I add an icon to an OCX made with Delphi so that it is visible in VB?

Tags: delphi, vb6, icons, delphi-2007, ocx

I made an OCX with Delphi 2007. Now my customer claims that there is no icon in his VB when he installs this OCX.

How can I add such an icon to my OCX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this old page](http://pw1.netcom.com/~cherrman/dl030.htm) the constructor of [TActiveXControlFactory](http://docs.codegear.com/docs/radstudio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate3/EN/html/delphivclwin32/AxCtrls_TActiveXControlFactory_Create.html) in the initialization section of your ActiveX Control unit has a parameter called ToolbarBitmapID  which is a resource id to a bitmap. That is how you set your icon.